# How do I split a string and put it into a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have a long string that I want to put into a dictionary format with an index and a key. The string looks like this:

```
"(\'unpredictable\', \'JJ\'), (\'man\', \'NN\')"
```

and so on and so on.

I want to split the string up and have each entry in the dictionary have the index match to the first part in the parenthesis and the key to the second part. In this example, my ideal dictionary would be like this:

```
{'unpredictable': 'JJ', 'man': 'NN'}
```

Whats the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is a representation of valid Python code.  This means that you can parse it with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) into a tuple of tuples and then call [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) on it:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> data = "(\'unpredictable\', \'JJ\'), (\'man\', \'NN\')"
>>> literal_eval(data)
(('unpredictable', 'JJ'), ('man', 'NN'))
>>> dict(literal_eval(data))
{'man': 'NN', 'unpredictable': 'JJ'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find all words using `re.findall`, then ziped it using slicing

```
>>> import re
>>> a="(\'unpredictable\', \'JJ\'), (\'man\', \'NN\')"
>>> k=re.findall('\w+',a)
>>> k
['unpredictable', 'JJ', 'man', 'NN']
>>> dict(zip(k[::2],k[1::2]))
{'unpredictable': 'JJ', 'man': 'NN'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 simplest ways, hope these helps.

1. ```
    >>> s="(\'unpredictable\', \'JJ\'), (\'man\', \'NN\')"    
    >>> dict(eval(s))  
    {'unpredictable': 'JJ', 'man': 'NN'}
   ```
2. ```
    >>> s="(\'unpredictable\', \'JJ\'), (\'man\', \'NN\')"     
    >>> dic={}  
    >>> for each in eval(s):  
    ...     dic[each[0]] = each[1]  
    ...
    >>> dic  
    {'unpredictable': 'JJ', 'man': 'NN'}
   ```